# xgboost how to copy model

Tags: python, xgboost

In the `xgboost` documentation they refer to a `copy()` method, but I can't figure out how to use it since if `foo` is my model, neither `bar = foo.copy()` nor `bar=xgb.copy(foo)` works (`xgboost` can't find a `copy()` attribute of either the module or the model). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `copy()` is a method of the `Booster` object, but a (say) `XGBClassifier` is *not* one, so if using the `sklearn` front end, you do
`bar = foo.get_booster().copy()`

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.base.clone()` will make a deep copy of a model without copying attached data.  It may be what you are looking for.  Just remember, it's a *function*, not a method, so don't make the mistake I did of sticking `.clone` after my identifier :-)

Usage :

```
## assume e as an estimator is defined and sklearn is already imported.
e = sklearn.base.clone(estimator)
e is estimator ## should return False
```

HTH